# Compare two tables of same Values in MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database that contains 2 tables for example

**Table A:**

```
Id: 1

name: ahmed

marks: 5
```

**Table B:**

```
Id: 1

name: ahmed

marks:
```

I want to compare Table B with Table A. If `Id` and `name` match Table B `id` and `name` then marks are inserted in Table B.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE B 
 SET B.Marks = A.Marks
FROM TableB B 
INNER JOIN TableA A ON  A.Name = B.Name 
                   AND  A.ID = B.ID
```

### c# code

```
string cs = @"Your connection string bla bla";

using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
  string sqlQuery = "UPDATE B SET B.Marks = A.Marks
                     FROM TableB B 
                     INNER JOIN TableA A ON  A.Name = B.Name 
                                            AND  A.ID = B.ID"
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con))
    { 
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```

Comment: @JunaidMumtazAhmed you have to post your ATTEMPT at the C# first to get help with it. There are many different ways to connect to a DB and create C# objects that relate to tables. You WANT is to vague and not what stackoverflow is about.

Comment: send me your project (+100$) and I'll do it for you :-p